# How to improve the following code in Objective-C?

Tags: ios4

I have the following code that displays the alerts depending on the result: How can I improve the following code:

```
-(IBAction)saveSettings:(id)sender
```

{
    UIAlertView *alert = nil;

```
username = self.usernameTextField.text; 
token = self.passwordTextField.text; 

// validate the username and token
if(![self isValid]) 
{
    // show alert that it is not valid

    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Invalid User Name or Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];


    [alert show];
    return; 
}

BOOL isSynched = [self syncSettings];

if(!isSynched) 
{
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error Syncing Settings" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [alert show];
}
else 
{
    alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Settings has been Synced Syncing" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

}

I think I am instantiating the alert too many times and looks kind of repetitive!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
username = self.usernameTextField.text; 
token = self.passwordTextField.text; 

UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                message:@""
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
[alert autorelease];

// validate the username and token
if(![self isValid]) 
{
    // show alert that it is not valid

    alert.message = @"Invalid User Name or Password";
    [alert show];
    return; 
}

BOOL isSynched = [self syncSettings];

if(!isSynched) 
{
    alert.message = @"Error Syncing Settings";
}
else 
{
    alert.title = @"";
    alert.message = @"Settings has been Synced Syncing";

}    
[alert show];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try leaving all those instances of `[alert show];` out & then at the end put...

```
if (!alert) return;
[alert show];
```

phix23's answer also provides good improvement because you're setting a bunch of the properties of the alert explicitly & only once. If you use that you can also use mine by changing the condition to...

```
if (alert.message != @"") return;
```

Cheers, Pedro :)